# DSpace - XMLUI Discovery - Sorting items applying numerical sort order to metadata containing text value

Tags: sorting, dspace, discovery

I would need to sort the items displayed on the XMLUI discovery a metadata containing a numerical value but saved as a string (specifically, a size in bytes).

Of course, I want the result of the sort to consider the numerical value of these strings rather than their textual value.

It is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I personally solved by applying, to the information contained in the metadata of reference for the sorting, not significant zeros on the left (left padding) in such number to obtain the same length for all the values in the same field and the desired result of a numerical sorting, while applying an alphabetical sort ("text" metadata).

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to know if this is possible.  Unfortunately according to the DSpace discovery documentation, only "text" and "date" are allowed as a data type.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery#Discovery-Searchfilters&sidebarfacetsCustomization

Comment: @eustachioMaselli, You should post this as an answer to your question.  I imagine that others will find the answer useful.